# Network disconnect each day almost same time

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, connection

I have dhcp server (win server 2008 R2). Got about 30 pc in network. But I am facing problems on 2 of them. I have set IP manually on them. Problem is, that these 2 comps disconnect from network between 2 and 3 pm each day. I thought that it would be problem with leasing time. But I cant find setting, where I can set lease time to static IP, or any kind of other setting which can solve my problem.

Comment: any event log entries on these workstations ? Like ip conflict

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the logs.
Disconnecting should be written in there, and why.

Maybe there is a 'schtasks' set and forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

Create IP reservation for those two clients in DHCP.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780311(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Do you also think it can be lease problem ?? Or any other ideas ...

Comment: Because those two IP addresses were not leased by DHCP, but was manualy requested by the clients. Try to make a reservation pool for those clients.

Comment: Yes, i think it's a lease issue.

Comment: It's not a lease issue... for three reasons: 1. Static ip addresses don't have a lease and therefore don't expire. 2. The problem would affect all DHCP clients, but only DHCP clients, not statically assigned ip addresses. 3. Only if the DHCP server was unavailable to renew the lease would the lease expire and the DHCP clients would lose their ip address.

Comment: If you use a static addresses (which is configured at the device) the correct way is to reduce DHCP lease pool (DHCP range), and then set the device to an ip address outside of the DHCP pool.

Comment: Whene you cerate DHCP reservations, then the reserved address should be within the DHCP pool.

Comment: dhcp poool start at 192.168.2.100 manual set IP are 192.168.2.74,76. If not lease problem any other ideas what can cause this porblem ??

Comment: You can use some realtime network monitor(wireshark)to investigate your issue. Just install it at the client side and make network capture around diconnect time. I think you will get some more information.